# Separate the variables of the function $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, convolution

Is there a way to express the function $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ as the product of two functions: $f(x)\cdot g(y)$, i.e. one in each variable?

This is becasue I want to apply a convolution whose kernel is define that way, and I am willing to separate that kernel. For that I need to be able to express it as a product of two functions that are on each variable separatedly.

Comment: Don't you mean f(x)g(y)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be done. Suppose to the contrary that it can be done. We will derive a contradiction. Suppose that $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=f(x)g(y)$ for some functions $f$ and $g$.  Then 
$$f(1)g(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},$$
and
$$f(1)g(2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$
and
$$f(2)g(1)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}$$
Note 
$$f(2)g(2)=\frac{f(1)g(2)f(2)g(1)}{f(1)g(1)}=\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{4}{5}.$$
But $f(2)g(2)=\frac{2^2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: And what about $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$? Thanks!

Comment: Same argument, slightly more pleasant to write out, no square roots!

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks a lot. And are you aware of any functions that could approximate the result, being  separable? This is, a function f(x,y) with similar "shape"? This is a computational problem so an approximation could work.

Comment: No good ideas, would have to know a lot more about the practical problem. So going to polars is not acceptable? Then $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ factors nicely as $r\cos^2\theta$.